# How do I clear the DOM contents inside a selector in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to load a Kenod Pivot grid wrapped in a Angular2 component. I load the kenod grid based on user event like button click event. When I load the kendo grid for the first time it loads fine. But when the user clicks the button repeatedly I want the previously loaded grid contents to be removed and load the new grid with latest data. Instead it behaves in a way such that it appends or loads the new grid just below the previously loaded grid. 
Please find the snapshot about the loading multiple instances of same component
[image]

I tried the following code to clear the existing DOM contents inside the specified selector.

```
 this.temp = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).children('#pivotgrd').html('');
this.dataSource = ... //assign json values to this...

this.pivotgrid = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#pivotgrd').kendoPivotGrid(
            this.dataSource
         ).data("kendoPivotGrid");
```

The selector in the HTML to load

```
<div>
    <div id="pivotgrd" class="hidden-on-narrow"></div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't works as expected.

Please let me know how do I clear the previously loaded contents.

Comment: You just have to remove the existing ones yourself. It is not angular's fault.

Comment: provide component code

Comment: @Dummy, let me know how to remove the existing ones? that's what i am looking for, the code which I specified above doesn't work as expected and I am not sure what is the correct way to remove the existing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how you remove DOM elements using jquery. Call this before adding new content to your pivot

```
jQuery('#pivotgrd').children().remove()
```